# Angular & Firebase - How to present an error message

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I have**

- Some HTML that allows the user to change their email by entering a new email and their existing password
- When the new email and password are entered, they are passed to an auth service to run the updateEmail method
- If the user enters and incorrect password, the console logs the following error:

> core.es5.js:1020 ERROR O {code: "auth/wrong-password", message: "The password is invalid or the user does not have a password."}

**Question**

1. How can I present an error message like this, or a custom one when this error happens? (through a standard JS alert)

**My Auth Service**

```js
 updateEmailAddress(email: string, password: string) {

    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, password);

    currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(function () {

      currentUser.updateEmail(email).then(function () {

        currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function () {
          // Email Sent
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // An error happened.
        });

      }).catch(function (error) {
        // An error happened.
      });
    });
  }
```

**Update**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';


@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  user: Observable<firebase.User>;
  redirectUrl: string;


  constructor(
    private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private router: Router) {
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }


  // Login Form
  login(email: string, password: string): Observable<boolean> {

    this.firebaseAuth.auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        this.router.navigate(['projects']);
        return Observable.of(true);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
        return Observable.of(false);
      });

    return;
  }


  // Account Management - Re-authenticate the user using the current email and current password, then call the update email and email verification methods
  updateEmailAddress(email: string, password: string) {

    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, password);

    currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(function () {

      currentUser.updateEmail(email).then(function () {

        currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function () {
          // Email Sent
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // An error happened.
        });

      }).catch(function (error) {
        // An error happened.
         alert(ErroAuthEn.convertMessage(error['code']));
      });
    });
  }


// Log out of Apollo
  logout() {
    this.firebaseAuth.auth.signOut();
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }


  // A method to use to check if the user is logged in or not
  isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    console.log(!!this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser);
    return !!this.firebaseAuth.auth.currentUser;
  }
}

export namespace ErroAuthEn {
        export function convertMessage(code: string): string {
          console.log('called');
            switch (code) {
                case 'auth/user-disabled': {
                    return 'Sorry your user is disabled.';
                }
                case 'auth/user-not-found': {
                    return 'Sorry user not found.';
                }

                case 'auth/wrong-password': {
                  return 'Sorry, incorrect password entered. Please try again.';
                }

                default: {
                    return 'Login error try again later.';
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: Do you really want to use a JS alert or display an element on the page that warns the user?

Comment: Hey Ompurdy. Ideally an element for a nicer UX. However, anything right now would suit so I can understand it :)

Comment: Just to clarify, that error in the console isn't generated by you is it? It's coming from the request?

Comment: I believe so yes. I haven't written anything to intentionally show it. I assumed it was part of the firebase code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be the best solution is to implement a function that for each error message from the documentation returns a more understandable user-friendly message.

```
export namespace ErroAuthEn {
        export function convertMessage(code: string): string {
            switch (code) {
                case 'auth/user-disabled': {
                    return 'Sorry your user is disabled.';
                }
                case 'auth/user-not-found': {
                    return 'Sorry user not found.';
                }
              .
              .
              .

                default: {
                    return 'Login error try again later.';
                }
            }
        }
 }
```

Then on your component you can call like this:

```
updateEmailAddress(email: string, password: string) {

    const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const credentials = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(currentUser.email, password);

    currentUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(credentials).then(function () {

      currentUser.updateEmail(email).then(function () {

        currentUser.sendEmailVerification().then(function () {
          // Email Sent
        }).catch(function (error) {
          // An error happened.
        });

      }).catch(function (error) {
      alert( ErroAuthEn.convertMessage(error['code']));
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: This looks awesome. Quick question (excuse the newbie question)...when you pass the message to the ErroAuthEn method how does the switch know which message to display? When / where is 'auth/user-disabled' determined?

Comment: check the firebase documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Error ideally you wanna do one message for each but you can use the default to have a generic message and just write for the most important ones.

Comment: Thanks Eduardo. I can't get this to work. I'll quickly update my code in my post. If you wouldn't mind, could you make sure I haven't missed anything please? Much appreciate your time.

Comment: Dont forget to import the nameSpace import { ErroAuthEn } from '../erro-auth-en.enum';

Comment: ah right. So they don't both go into my auth service? If not, what type of file is the 'ErrorAuthEn'? A service?

Comment: It can be a simple .TS file, not related to any angular specifics.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151069/discussion-between-megatron-and-eduardo-vargas).